# Book where brains are harvested and used as computers, bringing them back to life and driving them insane

Tags: story-identification, books, mind-control

It's a science fiction book from the seventies or likely earlier.  I might not remember it entirely correctly but the premise was that after someone dies their brain is harvested and wired into a computer to be used as a supercomputer.  No one realizes that this actually brings the brains back into consciousness, the assumption was that being dead they are just being used as biocomputers.  The huge pressure to solve mathematical problems drives the brains insane.  The main character wakes up in this situation but is somehow able to push the pressure aside.  Through telepathy he's able to find another brain in this situation and eventually somehow transfers his mind back into the body of a regular person and escape.

Comment: Do any of the books listed under the literature section of [TVTropes.org's **Wetware CPU** section](http://tvtropes.org/pmwiki/pmwiki.php/Main/WetwareCPU) sound familiar?

Comment: Did you read it in English? On the [Isolated brains in fiction](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Isolated_brain#Isolated_brains_in_fiction) list on wikipedia they mention a series called "Humans as Gods" featuring an alien society called the "Ruinators" that used harvested brains as organic computers, and one developed self-consciousness and was eventually granted a body, but the series' own wikipedia page says it has yet to be published in English.

Comment: It has some elements in common with '[Destination: Void](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Destination:_Void)', (disembodied brains used as computers and going nuts) but there's no Telepathy and redemption/escape for the brains..

Comment: Basic plot is pretty similar to "A Plague Of Demons" by Keith Laumer. Except that a few of the human brains retain their sanity, and since the brains are being used as computers in massive tanks to fight the alien's war . . . It all turns out unpleasantly for the brain-stealing race.

Answer (score 3):

It's not an exact match to the description, but I know also that sometimes memory is imperfect so... this reminded me immediately of [Wolfbane by Frederick Pohl & C.M. Kornbluth](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wolfbane_(novel)). Novel published in 1959, but I probably read it in the late 60's.

A wandering planet of mysterious giant pyramidal beings passes through our solar system and sweeps Earth along with it out into interstellar space. It is observed among the human survivors that when a person achieves a certain meditative state, they disappear.
Turns out that [spoiler alert] they are harvested by the Pyramids. Per Wikipedia:

> "To the Pyramids, the human race is nothing more than a useful source
> of 'Components' for a complex world-machine devoted mostly to feeding
> these artificial and semi-organic beings. (one human) is suspended in a
> fluid-filled tank and 'wired in' to the vast computer system. Later,
> he is linked to seven other humans as a 'Snowflake' - eight minds
> joined together to facilitate more complex tasks than a single human
> Component could manage.
>
> In this condition, (he) wakes, manages to retain his sanity, and wakes
> the other humans."

Rebellion, escape, etc.

Answer (score 2):

As in [this answer](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/45613/seeking-book-where-disembodied-brains-run-factories?rq=1), this is probably [*The Cybernetic Brains*](http://www.goodreads.com/book/show/8390800-the-cybernetic-brains) (1969) by William F. Jones.

[image: Book Cover - The Cybernetic Brains]

> It was a supercivilization, a Utopia. At its core were the Cybernetic Brains, brains taken from geniuses who were promised they would live forever.
>
> Then engineer Al Demming discovers the truth accidentally, the terrible truth transmitted to him by one of the brains. The brains are in reality slaves and in terrible torment. It was now up to Demming to stop the inhuman practice.
>
> Just when he planned to make the announcement to the Governing Board, Demming learned that the Board knew about the hideous living death. What was the real reason behind the facade? How could he convince the Board to suspend the system before the Brains revolted and destroyed the world?